# Performance Implications of Using a Method in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, webforms, ado.net

Instead of the traditional way of executing a query like this:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test VALUES (@FN, @LN, @DateAdded)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", txtFN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", txtLN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

I created a separate class that allows me to re-use a method to execute a query by determining the SQL statement and its parameters (names and values):

DB.cs

```
static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ConnectionString);

public static void Execute(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

which then allows me to lessen my coding process here:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO Test VALUES (@FN, @LN, @DateAdded)";
    SqlParameter[] parameters = {
        new SqlParameter("@FN", txtFN.Text),
        new SqlParameter("@LN", txtLN.Text),
        new SqlParameter("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now)
    };

    DB.Execute(SQL, parameters);
}
```

Are there any performance implications in doing these? Also, are there ways to improve the existing code? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see an issue with this technique, although this is probably more suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), however, I personally would not bother reusing the connection object. You don't gain anything from this, and it could cause you issues, simply use your configuration for a static connection string, and create a new SqlConnection object within the method and .NET connection pooling take care of the rest. In addition, you can simplify the code very slightly by using `command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);` instead of am explicit foreach loop.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for the **.AddRange** tip. I'll be re-using the connection object for the other methods in the same DB class. Is this advisable?

Comment: Ignore me, I didn't read the code properly. The static field will create a new connection object with each method call anyway, so you are already doing what I suggested just in a slightly less verbose way.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no performance difference between the two approaches, because in both cases you are using parameterized query. Since you are programming directly to `SqlCommand`'s methods (as opposed to `IDbCommand` methods) there is also no difference in portability to other RDBMS providers, because both implementations are tied to SQL Server.

You could make interface slightly easier to use by marking the second argument `params`, i.e.

```
public static void Execute(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
```

This would let you make a call like this:

```
DB.Execute(
    "INSERT INTO Test VALUES (@FN, @LN, @DateAdded)"
,   new SqlParameter("@FN", txtFN.Text)
,   new SqlParameter("@LN", txtLN.Text)
,   new SqlParameter("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now)
);
```